# Размер sidebar'a меняться с задержкой при скрытии нижнего меню браузера iOS Safari

Tags: css, safari

Есть навигация которая выезжает сбоку при нажатии на кнопку:

```
.nav{
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #0D0A0B;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: .5s ease;
    padding-top: 60px;
    display: block;
}
```

ПРОБЛЕМА: На iOS Safari при скролле вниз панель инструментов сворачивается. В этот момент сайдбар заполняет не весь экран по высоте (место, которое раньше было отведено для панели инструментов на секунду не заполняется сайдбаром), ну и через мгновение все нормально и сайдбар занимает 100% высоты экрана.
Ссылка на GitHub Pages (смотреть только из сафари на телефоне/планшете):
https://fkma13552.github.io/navIssue/

Хочется что бы не было такого скачка, как это можно исправить?

[image: до]

[image: во время]

[image: после]

Comment: `{  ̶h̶e̶i̶g̶h̶t̶:̶ ̶1̶0̶0̶%̶;̶ top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

При работе с `position fixed`, если Вы хотите что бы элемент занял всю площадь экрана, и не только `viewport'a`, то:

```
.nav {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 1;       
   width: 0;      
   background-color: #0D0A0B;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   transition: .5s ease;
   padding-top: 60px;
   display: block;
}
```

В вашем случае iOS Safari самостоятельно подстроил размер (пускай и с задержкой), но это справедливо не ко всем версиям данного браузера.

Comment: К сожалению эти правки не помогли. Браузер все так же не понимает, что этот бар нужно показывать на всю высоту. Спасибо за проявленный интерес к вопросу:)

Comment: Добавил ссылку на GitHub в описании проблемы